# How to use graphicspath in IfFIleExists?

Tags: floats, paths

Code where `IfFileExists` does not read `graphicspath`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\extrafloats{1000}
\usepackage{graphicx} % for importing .pdf images
\graphicspath{{/home/masi/Documents/Images/}}
\begin{document}
\foreach \ii in {1,...,62} {
  \IfFileExists{\ii.jpg}{1}{0}
}
\end{doument}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\graphicspath` just sets a path locally during graphics loading, if you want to set the same path for input etc as well replace

```
\graphicspath{{/home/masi/Documents/Images/}}
```

by

```
\makeatletter
\def\input@path{{/home/masi/Documents/Images/}}
\makeatother
```

alternatively (better) don't use `\graphicspath` and instead use

```
TEXINPUTS=/home/masi/Documents/Images/: pdflatex document
```

so things search there without needing any path in the document.

Comment: I think the last option assumes that your .tex document is also at the location. Right?

Comment: no, it just adds that directory to the default path (because of the trailing `:`)

Answer (score 0):

[David Carlisle's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/341531) is great if
you need "`graphicx`-awareness" from `\IfFileExists` as a document author.

If you're reading this question as a package writer, however,
you're probably seeking a way to handle both
users who have used `\graphicspath{...}` before loading your package, and
users who have just loaded your package.

`latexdef -p graphicx graphicspath` shows:

```
\graphicspath:
macro:#1->\def \Ginput@path {#1}
```

All that `\graphicspath` does is store its argument in a macro `\Ginput@path`, which will (most likely) be undefined otherwise.

So if `\Ginput@path` is defined, we can add its contents to `\input@path` just for the purposes of the `\IfFileExists` test
(that is, the original definition of `\input@path` will be restored after the test).

```
\makeatletter
% \input@path is not necessarily defined, but if it is,
% we don't want to erase its contents
\providecommand*{\input@path}{}
\newcommand{\IfImageExists}[3]{%
  % enclosing the possible redefinition of \input@path
  % and the \IfFileExists test in this group will
  % make \input@path revert to its previous definition after the test
  \begingroup
  % \ifdefined comes from eTeX, but
  % if you're using graphicx I suppose you're using eTeX
  \ifdefined\Ginput@path
    \edef\input@path{\input@path\Ginput@path}%
  \fi
  \IfFileExists{#1}{\endgroup #2}{\endgroup #3}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother
```

Comment: `\IfFileExists{#1}{\endgroup#2}{\endgroup#3}`